# getDay() jQuery addClass

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok guys, I am basically trying to show and hide content using getDay() and addClass().

It doesn't seem to be working for me at the moment.

I'd really like it to hide and unhide depending on the day.

Thanks in advance!

Here is my code:

```
<div class="sundayRadio">
                <div class="vertDiv"></div>
                <section class="schedule on_now">
                    <p>20:00 NEWS - DJ RANDOM</p>
                    <p>Description.</p>
                </section>
```

```
function applyclass()
{
var d = new Date();
var n = d.getDay();
if (n = 0)
// If day is Sunday
$('sundayRadio').addClass('show');
    $('mondayRadio').addClass('Dshow');
    $('tuesdayRadio').addClass('Dshow');
    $('wednesdayRadio').addClass('Dshow');
    $('thursdayRadio').addClass('Dshow');
    $('fridayRadio').addClass('Dshow');
    $('saturdayRadio').addClass('Dshow');
else if (n = 1)
// If day is Monday
$('sundayRadio').addClass('Dshow');
    $('mondayRadio').addClass('show');
    $('tuesdayRadio').addClass('Dshow');
    $('wednesdayRadio').addClass('Dshow');
    $('thursdayRadio').addClass('Dshow');
    $('fridayRadio').addClass('Dshow');
    $('saturdayRadio').addClass('Dshow');


else
//// Else please reload
$('reloadWarn').addClass('show');
    $('sundayRadio').addClass('Dshow');
    $('mondayRadio').addClass('Dshow');
    $('tuesdayRadio').addClass('Dshow');
    $('wednesdayRadio').addClass('Dshow');
    $('thursdayRadio').addClass('Dshow');
    $('fridayRadio').addClass('Dshow');
    $('saturdayRadio').addClass('Dshow');
}
window.onload = applyclass;

.show { display: block !important; }
.Dshow { display: none !important; }
```

Comment: You are missing "." operators on all your class names. That is, it should be `$('.sundayRadio')`. Clearly your code would be much simplified if you'd give those elements a common class name in addition to their identifying class names.

Comment: Where are your curly brackets?

Comment: updated still not working:
if (n == 0){
// If day is .sunday
$('.sundayRadio').addClass('.show');
    $('.mondayRadio').addClass('.Dshow');
    $('.tuesdayRadio').addClass('.Dshow');
    $('.wednesdayRadio').addClass('.Dshow');
    $('.thursdayRadio').addClass('.Dshow');
    $('.fridayRadio').addClass('.Dshow');
    $('.saturdayRadio').addClass('.Dshow');
}

Comment: see here & let me know if it works http://jsfiddle.net/C7JJM/102/

Comment: Works perfect on jsFiddle but when I apply it to my html no luck! Thanks for you time though, appreciate it!

Comment: Fixed! placed in <head> works perfect! Thanks so much for your help and everyone else that chimed in! Cheers guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got following problems in your code.

**1)** You are using selector like

```
$('mondayRadio').addClass('show');
```

Use `.` to get class selectors like bellow

```
$('.mondayRadio').addClass('show');
```

**2)** You are not comparing in `if` you are assigning

Say

```
if (n == 0)
```

instead of

```
if (n = 0)
```

I'd like to compare like bellow to avoid this problem.

```
if (0 == n)
```

**3)** You are not using `{}` to provide block to `if` properly.

Say like

```
if(n==0){
 //All your code
}
else if(n==1){
   //code
}
else{
   //code
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/C7JJM/102/)

Answer (score 1):

you are missing dots in your class-selectors:

wrong:

```
$('sundayRadio')
```

correct:

```
$('.sundayRadio')
```

and you are not comparing in your if-clauses:

wrong:

```
if (n = 0)
```

correct:

```
if (n === 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Where are your curly brackets?

- In *JavaScript*, whitespace means little
- Without curly brackets, the interpreter ends a block as soon as possible

For example,

```
if (false)
    console.log('1');
    console.log('2');
```

`"2"` will always be logged to the console

You need

```
if (false) {
    console.log('1');
    console.log('2');
}
```

for your expected behaviour

---

Further, your code as it is is almost definitely throwing `SyntaxError: Unexpected token else` due to this, so it may be useful to check your console when debugging

---

Finally, as pointed out by others, `n = 1` is an assignment, not a comparison, and will always *be* `1; // truthy` - You probably want to use `===`, and class selectors begin with a `.`, just like in *CSS* (it's the same syntax).

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
updated my code:
if (n == 0){
// If day is .sunday
$('.sundayRadio').addClass('.show');
    $('.mondayRadio').addClass('.Dshow');
    $('.tuesdayRadio').addClass('.Dshow');
    $('.wednesdayRadio').addClass('.Dshow');
    $('.thursdayRadio').addClass('.Dshow');
    $('.fridayRadio').addClass('.Dshow');
    $('.saturdayRadio').addClass('.Dshow');
}

Still not working